# How to authenticate with django-grahql-jwt in a graphene-django GraphQLTestCase?

Tags: python, django, graphql, graphene-django, django-graphql-jwt

I'm trying to test my mutation according to graphene django documentation. the mutation works with `@login_required` decorator and there's a problem because any method of login to test doesn't work. I tried with `self.client.login`, `self.client.force_login`. I've even made a tokenAuth mutation, and hardcoded some credentials there and it also doesn't work; the user is still Anonymous.

```py
def test_create_member_mutation(self):
    response = self.query(
        '''
        mutation createMember($firstName: String) {
            createMember(firstName: $firstName) {
                member {
                    id
                }
            }
        }
        ''',
        op_name='createMember',
        variables={'firstName': 'Foo'}
    )

    self.assertResponseNoErrors(response)
```

Comment: Are you using django's session authentication or graphql JWT?

Comment: @ruohola sorry, didn't specify it. graphql jwt

Comment: Well then you're lucky, I had the same issue also.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how I've solved it in my tests:

You can pass a token that has been made for the test user in the `headers` keyword argument of `self.query()`:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from graphene_django.utils import GraphQLTestCase
from graphql_jwt.shortcuts import get_token


class ExampleTests(GraphQLTestCase):

    def test_create_member_mutation(self):
        user = get_user_model().objects.get(pk=1)
        token = get_token(user)
        headers = {"HTTP_AUTHORIZATION": f"JWT {token}"}

        graphql = '''
            mutation createMember($firstName: String) {
                createMember(firstName: $firstName) {
                    member {
                        id
                    }
                }
            }
        '''

        response = self.query(
            graphql,
            op_name='createMember',
            variables={'firstName': 'Foo'},
            headers=headers,
        )
        self.assertResponseNoErrors(response)
```

Comment: I get: `TypeError: query() got an unexpected keyword argument 'headers'`, what versions of graphql and graphene do you have installed ? I read all the source code and found only `**extra`, no mention of headers.

Comment: @EmacsTheViking The parameters seems to be there still: https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene-django/blob/623d0f219ebeaf2b11de4d7f79d84da8508197c8/graphene_django/utils/testing.py#L75

Comment: Thanks ! I don't know why I didn't check the version before. I have 2.7.1 which is very old now, I joined the project and it was created a good while ago... I will upgrade. Thankyou.